# PHP fails to parse JSON - Unexpected Integer

Tags: php, json, api

I'm trying to make an application that will use a JSON input. Below is some code that shows the problem when run. The problem being a syntax error; unexpected integer from the "etag" line (`"$etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-10-31T23%3A22%3A09.7835369Z'\"",`). When I remove the etag line it runs fine but otherwise I get an error. Can I remove the etag line (not needed anyway) before being parsed or get around it some other way? I unfortunately cant change what the API sends.

```
<?php
$json = '{
  "Form": {
    "Id": "1",
    "InternalName": "SignUp",
    "Name": "Sign Up"
  },
  "$version": 7,
  "$etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-10-31T23%3A22%3A09.7835369Z'\"",
  "Email": "test@email.com",
  "Phone": "(123) 412-3412",
  "CarrierServiceProvider": "Sprint",
  "WTSKeywords": "Testing WTS",
  "WTBKeywords": "Testing WTB",
  "Id": "1-3",
  "Email_IsRequired": false,
  "Phone_IsRequired": false,
  "CarrierServiceProvider_IsRequired": true
}';

$data = json_decode($json); 

echo $data->Email; 
echo "\n"; 
echo $data->WTBKeywords; 
?>
```

Code should output: `test@email.com Testing WTB`

Comment: You need to escape the single quotes, since that's your delimiter around the string.

Comment: `"$etag": "W/\"datetime\'2019-10-31T23%3A22%3A09.7835369Z\'\"",`

Comment: This is only a problem when you put the JSON into a literal in the script. If you're getting the JSON from an API or file, it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You json string has both `'` and `"`, so you cannot simple use single or double quoted.

Use [heredoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like this,

```
$json = <<<EOT
{
  "Form": {
    "Id": "1",
    "InternalName": "SignUp",
    "Name": "Sign Up"
  },
  "$version": 7,
  "$etag": "W/\"datetime'2019-10-31T23%3A22%3A09.7835369Z'\"",
  "Email": "test@email.com",
  "Phone": "(123) 412-3412",
  "CarrierServiceProvider": "Sprint",
  "WTSKeywords": "Testing WTS",
  "WTBKeywords": "Testing WTB",
  "Id": "1-3",
  "Email_IsRequired": false,
  "Phone_IsRequired": false,
  "CarrierServiceProvider_IsRequired": true
}
EOT;

$data = json_decode($json); 

echo $data->Email; 
echo "\n"; 
echo $data->WTBKeywords;
```